# I want to start VM for specific time

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.04, time, linux-kvm

I am designing a system in which lot of VMs are there which run on KVM. My physical resources are limited, that is why I want to allow some of the VMs to run for some specific time(say Every Wednesday 2PM-6PM) and some other VMs on some other time(say Every Wednesday 6PM-10PM). Is there any way to do this.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 at host machine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this can help you:

[Timely start](https://superuser.com/questions/742924/is-it-possible-to-get-a-virtualbox-vm-always-start-from-same-time-if-so-how)

[timesync-latency-factor](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#idp57774448)

Comment: You are saying about "always start the VM from same time" and not about VM should be up for some specific time.I want my VM "can be" up in that time only and not in other time.I want to put some constraint on the up time of a VM