# Are there any NTP servers online which let machines sync to a different time (even years)?

Tags: ntp

I want to sync virtual machine (XP client on Virtualbox) to a time other than the host machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get a Virtualbox VM always start from same time, if so how?](http://superuser.com/questions/742924/is-it-possible-to-get-a-virtualbox-vm-always-start-from-same-time-if-so-how)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but are you trying to run old software with an expired license ?
That would make the question off-topic for this site...

But as the answer could be quite useful for other people I'm answering it anyway.

Just don't set any time-service and adjust the clock manually. That is by far the easiest solution.

VirtualBox has a whole lot of options to manipulate the clock of the VM. Check the manual for a extensive explanation. There is a whole chapter dedicated to this.

Comment: 1. Yes, I am trying to run expired, legacy Win32 (XP and older only) software in a VM. Virtualbox's XP time ALWAYS syncs back to the host time during reboot. I have tried all methods to fix Vbox time I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Many VirtualBox options are only available through the CLI. To disable time synchronization, use:

```
vboxmanage setextradata <name> VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled 1
```